# AmgularjJS checkbox ng-click not firing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

In my HTML view

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="campaign.paused" 
 ng-disabled="!edittingCampaign" 
 mg-click="CampaignPauseClicked(campaign, $event)" class="check_box" />
```

`CampaignPauseClicked()` never fires when I click the checkbox.

If i have an `ng-click` on the DI which encloses the checkbox, then **that** fires, but whether it is there or not, the checkbox click function is not firing. Also not when I change `ng-click` to `ng-change`.

Comment: is it typo in question `mg-click`? should be `ng-click`

Comment: change mg-click to ng-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `mg-click` instead of `ng-click`.

When using checkboxes maybe what you really want is [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

Comment: D'oh! Coding in a dark room, but maybe I need stronger prescription glasses. `ng-click` fires now, of course, but why prefer `ng-change`? Are they not equivalent?